# What is considered as revealing a sin

Tags: sin

What is considered as revealing a sin and if someone reveals their sin on this site is it considered as revealing a sin

Answer (score 0):

What is revealing a sin?

**Sin before God**

God knows all. A sin cannot be hidden from Him. It cannot be revealed before God.

**Consciousness**

To become aware that a deed is a sin or may be a sin is a first step. Some of the questions here are put in this stage to ask whether something is a sin.

**Confess to God**

Although God knows what we do and what we think, it is good for us to confess to God, to direct our thoughts. This is the beginning of repenting and asking for forgiveness.

Some questions here are about the proper way to repent.

**Reveal to other people**

Sin against ourselves or against God need not be confessed in public.
Unjustice against other people should be acknoledged, asking for forgiveness and if possible offer compensation.

As this site is pseudonymous, it offers the possibility to discuss sin in public without going public in person and reveal a sin to public.